# Chrome Kiosk Crash/Error Pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kiosk

**EDIT:**

Is there a way without creating an extension?

**EDIT 2:**

The urls passed in are linking to an api that relates to connectino error (as far as I understand)... I mean when the browser actually crashes... i.e. runs out of memory for example!

I am implementing a kiosk solution using Chrome...  I have got it securely locked down but I am having issues with one thing.

When chrome crashes (i am simulation a browser crash with javascript) it shows an error page.

From that error page you are able to go into google search and other google products.

My question is, is there a way to change or disable these error pages?

Thanks

Comment: Write an extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841256/change-chrome-4xx-page

Comment: You should ask another question rather than trying to reopen this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514883/create-a-custom-dns-error-page):

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(onErrorOccurred, {urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]});

function onErrorOccurred(details)
{
  if (details.error == "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED") // change this ERR to whatever
    chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: "..."});
}
```